# PHP </br> where lower-case letters meets uppercase-letter

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-split

I am trying to put  before every character which meets with a uppercase-letter. What I achieved is:

```
$str =  "Rating: goodHelps control sebum production Rating: averagePrevents the development of microorganisms in cosmetics Rating: badCan be allergenic Rating: badToxic to cell division"; 
$string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', "</br>", $str);

print_R($string);
```

Result:

> Rating: goo
>
> elps control sebum production Rating: averag
>
> revents the development of microorganisms in cosmetics Rating: ba
>
> an be allergenic Rating: ba
>
> oxic to cell division

It removes the first and after character as you can see. I need the full text with a .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use back-references to what you captured in the replace.  The first capture group `()` is `$1` and the second is `$2`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1</br>$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaround, this inserts `</br>` between lowercase and uppercase characters.

```
$str =  "Rating: goodHelps control sebum production Rating: averagePrevents the development of microorganisms in cosmetics Rating: badCan be allergenic Rating: badToxic to cell division"; 
echo preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', "</br>", $str);
```

**Output:**

```
Rating: good</br>Helps control sebum production Rating: average</br>Prevents the development of microorganisms in cosmetics Rating: bad</br>Can be allergenic Rating: bad</br>Toxic to cell division
```